# create new RelativeLayout Programmatically in Android

Tags: android, layout

my UI is like this :

[image]

every grid has some object , I want to no. seven is blank use RelativeLayout programmatically.

what do I do , Thanks.

Comment: You can use  custom grid view and programmatically can add object inside it while for 6th index or 7th item dont add anything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can change button border color with backgroundTint attribute.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
         <LinearLayout ...
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="0.9">
                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>

                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>

                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout ...
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="0.9">
                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>

                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>

                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout ...
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="0.9">
                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>

                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>

                  <Button android:width="match_parent"
                          android:height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="0.3"
                          android:background="@drawable/border"/>
         </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create border.xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"/>
</shape>
```